# What is the /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/casper-functions for?

Tags: initramfs

In my ubuntu-based system, everytime update-initramfs gets called I got errors like this:

```
.: 6: Can't open /scripts/casper-functions
```

So I took a look around and found the script casper-functions in /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts.

Using grep I found the scripts referencing /scripts/casper-functions.

Now I have two possibilities:

1. Comment out the lines referenciing the script (which shouldn't make any difference, I think, because it's not working anyway.)
2. Fix all refences to this script. (And fix a reference in the script itself)

I tried both and ran

```
dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

There haven't been any errors reported in any case. But before I do either of this (and reboot) I would like to know what this script does. I'm not really familiar with sh-scripts, so I couldn't figure it out, yet.

UPDATE:
I replaced all references of /scripts/casper-functions with /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/casper-functions and replaced /scripts/functions with /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/functions in casper-functions.

As result a created live-cd (remastersys - backup) won't boot anymore (it did boot before). So probably neither option may be well...

How can I get rid of these error messages then? I read something about "uninstalling canonincal-census-package", but I don't have it installed and I can't find it via apt-get. So I'm not able to install and uninstall it again as suggested in some forums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I appear to have done a successful workaround with the commands:

```
cd /
ln -s /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts
```

Comment: Sounds simple. Why didn't I come up with this myself. Thanks.